# Plotting CSV data with negative numbers using GNUplot

Tags: gnuplot

I'm newy on GNUplot, and I'd like to know how to plot from .csv or .txt file, I have written some code but always got an error like this, 
line 10: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
line 10: x range is invalid

and I don't know why,

I left the code written below, and some of the data i want to plot. 
I'd like to plot colum 1 as x and column 2 as y

```
#programa para graficar archivos de texto csv. 
set title '<Grafica de datos Sensor Tag 1>'
set ylabel '<Muestras>'
set xlabel '<mG>'
set grid 
set datafile separator ";"
set autoscale fix
set output '<Grafica ST1>.png'
set xrange [*:]
plot "sensor12.csv" using 2 with lines
#plot "sensor1.txt" u (column(0)):2:xtic(1) w l title "", "sensor1.txt" u      (column(0)):3:xtic(1) w l title "", "sensor1.txt" u (column(0)):4:xtic(1) w l title "" 

pause -1
```

I hope someone could help me

thanks 
RH

1547277933.638079,15.869141,136.718750,1019.287109
1547277933.640045,14.160156,134.765625,1014.160156
1547277933.642001,12.695312,132.812500,1011.962891
1547277933.643822,14.404297,135.742188,1018.554688
1547277933.645711,10.742188,134.765625,1016.845703
1547277933.647611,12.939453,133.056641,1022.705078
1547277933.649441,18.310547,132.324219,1012.939453
1547277933.651419,13.916016,134.033203,1017.822266
1547277933.653344,12.695312,134.521484,1015.869141

Comment: Remove the line `set datafile separator ";"` from your script, you have spaces as separators which is the default

Comment: Please the datafile as text not as png

Answer (score 0):

In your original data image you showed a table screenshot, which let Christoph infer that your datafile separator was whitespace.
However, your text file data is actually comma separated. As Thor mentioned, please always provide data as text.
So, replace your line `set datafile separator ";"`

with

```
set datafile separator ","
```

or

```
set datafile separator comma
```